# Include HTML content from external url in Magento2

Tags: magento2, javascript, html, external

I have HTML file which is hosted on other server.

http://testsite.com/test/index.html

which has the content like this(As a example)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>    
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" type="text/css">
 <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="homepage">
<div id="testdiv" class="test-container">
 <div id="text">
  <div class="center"><h2>Welcome page</h2>
  <h3>Custom text goes here...</h3>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body></html>
```

I have to integrate the above HTML code with functionality in magento footer

So I tried in following way.

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/default.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="3columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body> 
 <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" 
      template="before_body.phtml" name="before_body_js"/>
    </referenceContainer>
<referenceContainer name="footer" remove="true" />
<referenceContainer name="footer-container">
        <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Index" name="custom_footer" before="-" template="customfooter.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
   </body>
 </page>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Index.php**

```
<?php
  namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
  class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
  {
   public function getCustomFooter()
   {    
   $url = 'http://testsite.com/test/index.html';
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    if(curl_exec($ch)){
     $footer = curl_exec($ch);                  
     $footer = preg_replace('#<script(.*?)>(.*?)</script>#is', '', $footer));
     $footer = trim(preg_replace([
                # Strip tags around content
                '/\<(.*)doctype(.*)\>/i',
                '/\<(.*)html(.*)\>/i',
                '/\<(.*)head(.*)\>/i',
                '/\<(.*)body(.*)\>/i',
            ], '', $footer));
       return $footer;
     }
   }
  }
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/customfooter.phtml**

```
<?php
   echo $block->getCustomFooter();
?>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/before_body.phtml**

```
 <?php
     $scopeConfigInterface = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()- >get(\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface::class);
     $customjs = $scopeConfigInterface->getValue("customfooter/general/footercontent", 
     \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE); // This returns <script src="http://testsite.com/test/js/custom.js" src_type="url"></script>
  ?>
  <?= /* @noEscape */ $customjs; ?>
```

In the admin I have an option to add javascript file src which will load before the body end tag .

The above code loads the HTML content properly in magento footer, but the js and other functionality is not working. mainly the code written in js is not working.
http://testsite.com/test/js/custom.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.scrolltoTop').click(function () {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
    return false;
   });
  if ($(".itemText").length) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".customdiv").fadeOut("slow");
    }, 3000);
  }
 });
 function add(a, b) {
  /// custom code
  }    
}
```

Please someone help me on this, How can I load the external HTML content with js and css files into the magento footer and content area.

Please suggest without requirejs-config.js approach, I have the requirement to achieve without that.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: which js is not working?

Comment: The custom code written in the js file http://testsite.com/test/js/custom.js

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Is the JS file loading but not being evaluated? Is it not loading? Are there are errors? What status code does the JS file have? Give us something to work off please.

Comment: Also, why not just use an iframe?

Comment: Without requirejs, you have to ensure that jQuery loads before you start referencing it as "$". You also have to resolve any other conflicts or race conditions that might create problems. Since the purpose of requirejs is to eliminate these issues, and since it is built in to Magento2 by default, why the requirement to not use it?

Comment: Yes, I have requirement to load the content from external URL, I am reading the content of that file and including js in this way